# sql Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-workbench, workbench

this works

```
INSERT INTO my_table(column1) values (TIMESTAMP('2009-03-29','04:07:54'));
```

this doesn't

```
INSERT INTO my_table(column1) values (TIMESTAMP('2009-03-29','03:07:54'));
```

Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-29 03:07:54' for column 'column1' at row 1

I'm working in mysql workbench.
data type for column1 is TIMESTAMP;

`CREATE TABLE my_table (
    column1 TIMESTAMP
    );`

Comment: can you send the create table query?

Comment: What is `table(t1)` supposed to be? If `table` is the name of your table, enclose it in backticks.

Comment: CREATE TABLE my_table (
    column1 TIMESTAMP
    );

Comment: I tried with datetime instead of timestamp and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me its working fine for both statement

```
INSERT INTO t1 values (TIMESTAMP('2009-03-29','04:07:54'));

INSERT INTO t1 values (TIMESTAMP('2009-03-29','03:07:54'));
```

while creating table tried giving both types Datetime and timestamp..

what is the data type for this column??

Comment: the data type is TIMESTAMP

Comment: tried both the types datetime and timestamp, its working for me. what is version of mysql ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
INSERT INTO my_table values (TIMESTAMP('2009-03-29','04:07:54'));
```